# Watch App storyboard replaces ✔ (checkmark) with weather icon

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, watchkit, watchos-2

I wanted to use the ✔ (code 2714) in my Watch app. But in the storyboard when paste it in a Label, on validation the checkmark is replaced by a weather icon.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Have you tried setting it directly from special symbol gallery? Select the lable text field, go to `Edit->Emoji & Symbols` and choose your symbol.

Comment: Yes this works but it seems to be a different checkmark !

Comment: There are two variants available for this symbol. One is under `Objects and Symbols` section while another is under `Bullets and Stars` section. Check which one is suitable for you.

Comment: One more thing, rendering style depends on Platform As well. See the difference for same unicode at different platform. [http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

Comment: From my observation it seems any emoji character will render differently when used within a label (using the default font). It might be a bug...

Comment: I have the same experience with a different emoji. It does display correctly on the watch. This behavior was introduced when they added the new emojis between iOS 9.0 & 9.1. Probably it is just an offset bug in Xcode.